# How force Ionic 4 back button to always goto a certain Page from selected pages

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am porting my Ionic 3 app to Ionic 4. I have switched over to using the new routing, with lazy loaded modules etc.

I have a side menu where I can select my main pages from any other page.

However, whenever I click the back button from one of the main feature pages, I always want to go back to the main home page (and not back to perhaps another feature page in the current route stack)

The click handler code in the Ionic 4 version for the side menu selection is as follows (pageItem.pageRoutePath contains the new route)

```
      public openPage(pageItem: AppPageItem): void {
        try {
          this.logger.debug(`openPage ${pageItem.title}`);
          
          // Try to force homepage to be where the back button takes us (but this doesn't seem to work)
          this.navController.navigateRoot(Constants.vals.pageRoutePaths.home, { replaceUrl: true });
          if (pageItem.pageRoutePath != Constants.vals.pageRoutePaths.home) {
            this.navController.navigateForward(pageItem.pageRoutePath);
          }
        } catch (error) {
          this.logger.error(`openPage ${error}`);
        }
      }
```

*The `{ replaceUrl: true }` parameter was me experimenting trying to get this to work, but it did not make any difference.*

In Ionic 3 I could do what I am describing as follows...

```
this.nav.setRoot(HomePage);
  if (pageItem.page != HomePage) {
    this.nav.push(pageItem.page); 
  }
```

I don't want this from **every** page, just my **feature** pages, eg some of the feature pages navigate to "details: pages, and here I do want the back button to just return back to the page it was navigated from, ie the default behavior.

How can I achieve this in Ionic 4?

### Update 28-Apr-19

I thought I could just use..

```
 this.navController.navigateForward(pageItem.pageRoutePath, { replaceUrl: true });
```

It works if there is only one extra page, but not if there is a whole stack - so the question remains open (so removed this as an answer).

Answer (score 0):

We can use router to do this:

```
let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
skipLocationChange: true,
replaceUrl: true
 };


//Where page is the page where app will navigate
this.router.navigate([’/page’], navigationExtras);
```